Python, разбитие цельной строки на символы
К примеру есть переменная lst:
lst='e4'

Вопрос, как разбить содержимое данной переменной на 2 значения 'e' и '4'?

А вам точно нужны две переменные? А то lst[0] и lst[1] просто использовать

a, b = lst. Это если там точно два символа.

MBo, да, именно два символа, отсюда и вопрос (был), как обратиться к отдельному элементу.

print(list(lst))

Пришёл к такому решению.
